# How to get file Url of Slow motion video from Asset?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avasset, avcomposition

I am getting file url of normal video, but slow motion video asset type is `AVComposition`. I am try with `AVAssetExportSession` But it consuming large time.

```
PHVideoRequestOptions *options=[[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *avAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {

     if(([avAsset isKindOfClass:[AVComposition class]] && ((AVComposition *)avAsset).tracks.count == 2)) {

         //Output URL of the slow motion file.
         NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
         NSString *documentsDirectory = paths.firstObject;
         NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mergeSlowMoVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];
         NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

         //Begin slow mo video export
         AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:avAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
         exporter.outputURL = url;
         exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
         exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

         [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 if (exporter.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
                 }
             });
         }];
     } else if ([avAsset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]) {
     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

`PHImageRequestOptions.version` property's default value is `PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent`.

Simply assign the version to `PHImageRequestOptionsVersionUnadjusted` or `PHImageRequestOptionsVersionOriginal` will return the original slow motion video.

```
PHImageRequestOptions * options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];

options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionUnadjusted;
// or 
options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;
```

Hope this is useful to someone.